# ASP.NET css style sheet edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, stylesheet

Basically I need to edit a css file and save it.

I have an ASP.NET c# web page and I'd like the admin to change some styles from the admin panel, just some colors, background colors, font sizes...

For example I'd like them to select a color and press a button to update it. In the code behind I'd like to access the css file and change it in a position I know, saving the file after that.

Is this possible? Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very broad and/or vague. It would help if you told us  [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far, or use [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to try and improve your question.

Comment: what I need is to access the css file and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is storing admin settings in database,and when the page loads change the style of the page by javascript .For example save the background color of the page in database and at page loading time restore it and save it in a string variable like 'Color' and then call the js method like `setBackGroundColor(<%Color%>)` and javascript function :

```
function setBackgroundColor(color)
{
    document.getElementById("#bodyId).style.background=color;
}
```

.

Comment: The site admin is going to change the colors or other styles just a few times a year. I'd like to keep all the styles in a text file, but change this text file (.css) directly from codebehind.

Comment: It's not difficult :).You can have a function in your code to access the relative path of your css file then you can modify it,the biggest problem is you must be careful about changing css file to not make it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store your CSS values in a table and your admin screen would update those. Then you create an ASPX page that generates your style on the fly (make its Response.ContentType "text/css") and link to it with the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyDynamicStyleSheet.aspx" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You should also set up some type of cacheing for your page so it's not hitting the DB unneccesarily.